# conversion of special character string

Tags: c#, asp.net, replace

i am using a web service and result is coming like this

> " methew wade watto"

then I've tried with `string.replace()`:

```
jsona = jsona.Replace(@"", "");
```

but the problem is i am unable to replace special character's like `"` this in my replace statement, How can I replace `"` from the input string? and what are the other options of replacing the string other then this?

Comment: Why don't you try to parse the JSON data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In c#, The `@` symbol means to read that string literally, and don't
>   interpret control characters otherwise. whereas `\` followed by a
>   character that is not recognized as an escaped character, matches that
>   character.

So you have to use `\"` to represent `"` in `.Replace()` instead for `@`
I think you have to try something like this:

```
string jsonInput = "\"methew wade watto\""; // be the input 
string replacedQuotes = jsonInput.Replace("\"", "");
```

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8LxO3t)

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the `"` with `\` , right now, you are just saying to replace empty string with empty string:

```
jsona= jsona.Replace("\"","");
```

Now this will replace the `"` sign in your string with empty string.

### Output:

> methew wade watto

Answer (score 0):

Use a backslash to determine special character

```
string = string.Replace("\"", "");
```